# Memory out of bounds once function exits despite heap allocation?

Tags: c, scope, allocation, heap-memory

General problem: implementing a dictionary.

Specific problem: according to gdb, my allocations and everything are working exactly as intended. The problem arises once types_dict_add is called with a key of "c". Everything is once again allocated as it should be and the entire dictionary is intact throughout the function context (all pointers are accessible and the structures at those pointers have their set values), but once the function exits back to main, the `mydict` pointers are all out of bounds. The actual pointer addresses stored in the `mydict` are all unchanged, but are suddenly inaccessible. Up until the call with "c", the `mydict` is also intact and as it should be in main.c

What am I doing wrong here? It's really confusing me as I've checked with gdb over and over again and the `len` value is being set correctly so there is definitely a proper amount of space being `realloc`'d each go.

**types.h**

```
#ifndef _TYPES_H_
#define _TYPES_H_

union types {
    long int ival;
    char *sval;
};

struct kv {
    char* key;
    union types val;
};

struct kv    **types_dict_init();
void           types_dict_add(struct kv**, char*, union types);
struct kv     *types_dict_get(char*);
void           types_dict_free(struct kv**);

#endif
```

**types.c**

```
struct kv **
types_dict_init()
{
    struct kv **newdict;

    newdict = calloc(1, sizeof(struct kv*));
    newdict[0] = NULL;

    return (newdict);
}

void
types_dict_add(struct kv** d, char* k, union types v)
{
    int len;

    if (d[0] == NULL) {
        d = realloc(d, sizeof(struct kv*) * 2);
        d[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct kv));
        d[0]->key = k;
        d[0]->val = v;
        d[1] = NULL;
    } else {
        for (len = 1; d[len - 1] != NULL; len++)
            ;
        d = realloc(d, sizeof(struct kv*) * ++len);
        d[len - 2] = malloc(sizeof(struct kv));
        d[len - 2]->key = k;
        d[len - 2]->val = v;
        d[len - 1] = NULL;
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bencode/types.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct kv **mydict;
    union types toadd;

    toadd.sval = "test";
    mydict = types_dict_init();
    types_dict_add(mydict, "a", toadd);
    types_dict_add(mydict, "b", toadd);
    types_dict_add(mydict, "c", toadd);
    types_dict_add(mydict, "d", toadd);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, mydict[i]->key);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `types_dict_add` you modify the local variable `d`. This change is not reflected in `main`'s variable `mydict`, because C passes function arguments by value. You will need to add an extra level of indirection if you want `types_dict_add` to be able to do `realloc` on `mydict`.

I think it would be simpler to use length-counting instead of a terminating NULL; then you can make your controlling structure be something like:

```
struct dict
{
    struct kv **members;
    size_t n_members;
};
```

This would also avoid a triple pointer (some people are uncomfortable with those).

Comment: But it's working for "a" and "b". Is that just luck?

Comment: You may be using a pointer to `free`d memory even by the `"b"` call, so it seems a lot of luck is involved :)  `realloc` may or may not re-use the same block , depending on whether there had been allocations after that block in memory already.

Comment: So I'd need to pass &mydict to types_dict_add for this setup to work? (This is not to say I won't be implementing your idea of keeping count as that's more C-like anyway).

Comment: Yes, and the function would take `struct kv ***`, and you'd use `(*d)` in the function to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the return value of `realloc`. `realloc` may fail in some cases.

`d = realloc(d, sizeof(struct kv*) * 2);`

do the check before accessing `d`.

Comment: The realloc and malloc is working as it is returning a valid pointer even during the problematic function call. (Checked with gdb)

Comment: Just expanding on this; if you want to gracefully handle realloc failure then you need to do:  `p = realloc(d, .....); if ( !p ) { /* failure handler */ } else { d = p; }`

Comment: The code in my question is very, very rough. I'm just trying to get the data structures working before even considering errors (I know that the *alloc family can fail and they should be checked for that). @MattMcNabb I looked at your profile and you have a lot of C experience. What do you think of using goto for failing out?

Comment: I don't think very highly of `goto`... every time I've used it in real code, I've immediately decided afterwards there was a better option and rewritten it.  I would have a separate function dedicated just to growing the structure though, e.g. `types_dict_add` would call the grow function; return a failure code if growing failed, and copy the value in if growing succeeded.  I'm also not sure where you're going with the `union` as currently there is no way of indicating which member of the union is in use; I guess you are getting around to that :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb EDIT: Yeah, you're right about the union. I jumped to using it and I should use a struct instead probably. Good idea on the extra growing function too. I haven't written with a C mindset in a while :)